# Travelling from the UK to Canada with muddy running shoes in my luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, airports, clothing

I'm travelling from the UK to Canada and I want to take my running shoes, but they are rather muddy.

Is it a problem to take muddy running shoes in my baggage from the UK to Canada? Will I have a problem at customs?

Comment: Probably if caught. Be safe and wash them.

Comment: Better wash them then...

Comment: The US customs agency will apparently wash your muddy shoes for you if you declare them.  Maybe Canada does the same.

Comment: Simply use a plastic bag. I do not think muddy shoes are a problem in itself, but customs/control will probably take a closer look because it may give the impression you plan to hide something inside by making it intentionally repellent....

Comment: @ThorstenS. It's a plant/animal disease and/or invasive plant species control issue. Like many countries asking if you've visited a farm recently.

Comment: @mkennedy exactly, i'll wash the shoes, I just couldn't find the answer to my question, and wondered what the situation is

Comment: @phoog They do?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen So I've heard.  I believe that information comes from a comment somewhere on this site, probably from at least a couple of years ago.  Unfortunately, comments are not searchable.  I've never tried it myself.

Comment: @phoog: I assume they give you a chance to clean them, or to throw them away, if they suspect you could be contaminating their environment. I know that isolated ecosystems like Australia, NZ, or Chile do this.

Comment: @QuoraFeans See for example [Why do some countries require everyone entering to see a customs officer, and some don't?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/50642/19400).  They do actually disinfect the shoes for you, presumably so they can be certain that the job was done effectively.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen see [Why do some countries require everyone entering to see a customs officer, and some don't?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/50642/19400).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might depend on the year. Some years ago when there was a foot-and-mouth pandemic in the UK, they were stricter on entering Canada than they are usually (including [a mat](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/1270148.stm) for everyone to walk on).

Once (maybe a different year) I entered with muddy hiking boots. They immersed the boots in something for me (formaldehyde perhaps) and gave them back to me in a sealed plastic bag ... I expect they would have been within their rights to confiscate and destroy them, though. Since then, obviously, I scrape and rinse any mud off them before flying.

Answer (score 43):

According to the Canada [Border Services Agency](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/fpa-apa/menu-eng.html):

> Many different kinds of items can introduce foreign threats into
>   Canada. These include things as diverse as:
>
> - Food, such as raw or cooked meats, fruit/vegetables, milk;
> - Homemade articles, such as items made from plants or wood;
> - Houseplants;
> - Live animals, including pets;
> - Firewood;
> - Plant cuttings, seeds; and
> - **Muddy hiking boots.**
>
> ...
>
> **Be sure to clean all soil and organic debris off of any items
>   including hiking boots, vehicles, boats and gardening and construction
>   tools/equipment.**

They might throw them away if there is enough mud on them to cause the agent to be concerned. To be safe, just wash your shoes before you pack them.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious as to why you would even entertain this notion in the first place, though. Why would you not simply _wash your stuff_ before packing it for a trans-Atlantic voyage? Why would you take grubby, muddy items of clothing as-is? Yuk.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition -- I'm not the OP, but my travels have led me into strange circumstances, where time or space constraints kept me from doing the "simple", convenient things.

Comment: @Malvolio:  but those constraints usually come up at the last minute, when there isn't time to post a question here.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: on the *outward* trip of a holiday, sure, I’d always wash things before leaving.  But before the return flight?  Time is at a premium, facilities may be unpredictable and sub-optimal — I often pack clothes/shoes dirty and wash them at home.

Comment: I mostly wear my hiking boots on the flights, as they are so big to pack. And some days you walk through mud on the way to the airport and boot cleaning facilities are not always easy to find on strange airports.

Comment: "[...] just wash your shoes before you pack them" — best advice I've read so far

Comment: For the genuinely curious: I didn't ever really intend to take my running shoes without cleaning them, I just wondered what the situation was. Or maybe I was half thinking of it, I live in a rural area, I run in the mud 4 to 6 times per week, cleaning my running shoes is an exercise in futility.